# firing emacs changes my keyboard layout to english-gb

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

The problem that I have is that I can not get the double quotes and tilde characters. At each session I have to use

> `setxkbmap -layout us`

after this command, performing a query as such below

```
setxkbmap -query -v 10
```

> Setting verbose level to 10 locale is C Trying to load rules file
>   ./rules/evdev... Trying to load rules file
>   /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev... Success. Applied rules from evdev:
>   rules:      evdev model:      pc105 layout:     us Trying to build
>   keymap using the following components: keycodes:
>   evdev+aliases(qwerty) types:      complete compat:     complete
>   symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev) geometry:   pc(pc105) rules:      evdev
>   model:      pc105 layout:     us

Then with the terminal, I can get these characters. But if I fire emacs, then the problem starts and I can not get the characters correctly anymore.

After firing emacs, output of setxkbmap -query -v 10

> Setting verbose level to 10 locale is C Trying to load rules file
>   ./rules/evdev... Trying to load rules file
>   /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev... Success. Applied rules from evdev:
>   rules:      evdev model:      pc105 layout:     gb Trying to build
>   keymap using the following components: keycodes:
>   evdev+aliases(qwerty) types:      complete compat:     complete
>   symbols:    pc+gb+inet(evdev) geometry:   pc(pc105) rules:      evdev
>   model:      pc105 layout:     gb

I can not understand why emacs changes this layout system wise, most probably, I have to read emacs manuals but maybe someone can answer faster.

Edit 1 :

Output of

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard

XKBMODEL='pc105'
XKBLAYOUT='us'
BACKSPACE='guess'
XKBVARIANT=''
XKBOPTIONS=''
```

Comment: What does the command `cat /etc/default/keyboard` output?

Comment: @Gunnar, see the edit, I guess there is no problem there...

Comment: Right. Maybe there is a keyboard layout setting in Emacs.